# The 7-th derivative of $ x^3 \cdot\tan(2x) $ is this right

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have to find $y^{(7)}\left(0\right)$ of $y(x)=x^3\cdot\tan{(2x)}$

So my idea was to use Taylor expansion for $\tan(2x)$ to the $7$-th element and then multiply the hole thing by $x^3 $ and then replacing $x$ with $ 0$, since $ x^3$ isn't 7-th times differentiable. My question is, is this allowed  and if yes when and how. If not any ideas for an easy way of doing it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hin:** Note that $\tan(2x)$ is an **odd** function, as is $x^3$, so the product is an even function.

**Remark:** The general idea of your procedure will also work. Note that you only need to find the expansion of $\tan(2x)$ up to the term in $x^4$, since we multiply the expansion of $\tan(2x)$ term by term by $x^3$.  And you really only need the $x^4$ term, which brings us back to the hint.

Finding the expansion by repeated use of the Product Rule is more complicated.

By the way, $x^3$ is differentiable arbitrarily often, it is just that the derivatives after a while are very uninteresting.